# Received a FaceTime call from unknown person

Tags: iphone, facetime

I have received a FaceTime call from unknown source. I'm not sure who this person is, nor do I know the caller's email.

What can I do? I don't want unknown people contacting me. It was from an iCloud email address.

Comment: What could it have happen? Im don't like tha unknown specialy if they are facetime calls.

Comment: Anyone can call anyone. You cannot stop someone from calling you. Do not answer the phone if you don't know who is calling.

Answer (score -1):

Block that caller! And if he or she calls again just contact Apple and they will help you resolve the problem! Just follow my steps and you will be fine!

Comment: Would you mind posting the necessary steps?